# Updating a date in a work flow of ssis

Tags: date, ssis

Fist of all I am kind of new working with SSIS and I need help with this problem.

I got the next work flow, everything was working good until I got an error related with a date in the source. The error is this: the year of some dates is like 0001 (oracle source), but this is not accepted by sql server (I can not change the kind of type established for this field in the data base). I have the next workflow, where I was redirecting this error (image 1):

[image]

Now, I need to do something like this:

IF date < '1900-01-01'
then date = '1900-01-01'

So, I thought a solution like in the image 2, using a derived column. But I do not know how to express the if condition in SSIS, or even better if this is the best approach to deal with this issue.

Regards

Comment: This is my personal opinon after years of doing production support and develpoment of SSIS packages. I try never to do any data celan up in the data flow. I bring fdata into a staging table in one data flow, then inteh control flow I use execute SQl tasks to do the clean up and then I use another datflow to take the cleaned data to the production tables. This is far easier to debug when something wierd happens in the data and a process that has worked fine for serveral years breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integration Services Expression Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141232(v=sql.105).aspx)

The closest the SSIS Expression language has to an `if` is the ternary operator `condition?true:false`

`Condition` is anything that results in a boolean, true/false, value. In your case `[date] < (DT_DATE)"1900-01-01"`

Here I'm converting my string date of 1900-01-01 to a strongly typed type for comparison to my "date" field. You'd want to align that type with what is represented in the data flow, be it: DT_DATE, DT_DBTIMESTAMP, etc

`true` is what the value should be when the condition is true. One of the challenges you'll run into is keeping your data types consistent. Same caveats as above but you'd likely need something like `(DT_DATE)"1900-01-01"`

`false` see above but for the false condition.  This is easier as there is no type conversion required. `[date]`

Thus

```
([date] < (DT_DATE)"1900-01-01") ? (DT_DATE)"1900-01-01" : [date]
```

Comment: crystal clear!. It worked perfectly with some modification in the work flow

Comment: @d2907 Please mark as answer as you stated "it worked perfectly..."